# cloning a meteor app

Tags: meteor

Copying a static website, i.e., HTML, CSS, JS is very simple.

Copying a dynamic website, i.e., is difficult due to the server-side scripts.

I'm concerned about cloning any meteor app as most of the server-side scripts are eliminated and the only thing which needs to be copied is the database, the schema can be easily obtained from the meteor live app and data can be easily scraped from the existing meteor app.

If a successful meteor app can be easily cloned, no one would prefer to develop an app on meteor.

Is there a way to stop cloning an existing meteor app?

Comment: Where would you copy all these scripts from? And what do you mean by 'server-side scripts are eliminated' and 'schema can be easily obtained from meteor live app'?

Answer (score 3):

Well, technically a meteor app can be cloned it depends on your directory/file structure & whether you're using it in development mode. If you're using one file and this sort of structure to seperate your code:

```
if(Meteor.isClient) {

}
if(Meteor.isServer) {

}
```

Because this file would be sent down to the client so someone can fetch it.

So it might be better to move to this structure

```
/client  - Place stuff in Meteor.isClient in a new js file
/server  - Place your server side code in a new js file
/public  - Place other public folder stuff
```

So no one will see the server side scripts, so they can't clone the backend of your app.

**Production mode/Dev mode**

In addition if you run your Meteor app in 'production mode' the [Javascript is packed](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS), handlebars & handlebars templates are [precompiled](http://www.eventedmind.com/posts/handlebars-precompiling).

In my opinion, it might be actually **harder** to copy a Meteor app to the previous types of web apps because HTML is rendered on the client side, fetching the html files will actually get back empty html files, if you even prettify the large JS file still leaves back precompiled handlebars templates. In addition files are merged into one!

So thats when it comes to cloning it to another meteor app. Even if getting the client script is available (as with any other stack) there are even more hurdles with Meteor when it comes to replicating the server script:

**DDP**

Attempting to clone it to a PHP/Server side script stack might be even harder because POST/GET aren't even used, DDP is used instead.

**Schema**

Width regards to the schema, you can control what the client sees via `Meteor.publish`, so they won't actually see the whole schema

Comment: While the question is valid, I strongly feel that it should not be asked here on stackoverflow

Comment: I agree it goes a bit into the dark area of stuff but I think meteor is safe from this if its all done right

Comment: @Akshat Thanks Nice insight into meteor. I'm still new to meteor, i still need more lessons.